# How can I link to revision history on Google Docs?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

When I load revision history in Google Docs, it does not change the URL. Is it possible to link to a history entry in Google Docs?

Comment: I don't see how. I think the best you can do is restore the revision you want, copy it to a new file, then go back to the original revision.

Comment: This would be important i.e. in document audits.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In Google Sheets (but not Docs) I was able to get a permalink for a particular from/to revision pair.

1. While in the Google Sheet, enable your browser's developer tool
2. In the Sheet, select **File -> See Revision History**
3. Click on the appropriate Revision in the Revision History panel
4. Review the developer tool "network" feature for a request that looks similar to this...
       `docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mbdW_BI1lsA1yQE35sTO1JYfHpGmJfqZVjiuU9jh-NA/revisions/show?sid=44116a28bf8fda09&rev=5&fromRev=2&gid=0`

   - if you are feeling lucky, you can try changing the values of `fromRev` and `rev` to show the difference between other revisions.
   - this URL is sufficient to share as a permalink
5. If you want to make the permalink page view a bit more userfriendly, make these changes.

   - change `/revisions` to `/notify`
   - change `sid=` to `s=`
        `https:///docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mbdW_BI1lsA1yQE35sTO1JYfHpGmJfqZVjiuU9jh-NA/notify/show?s=44116a28bf8fda09&rev=5&fromRev=2&gid=0`

You can see a video of this process [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/beyond-code-how-can-i-link-revision-history-google-sheets-sawatzky).

Comment: Great find! Hopefully Google will realize how useful this is to the end user and make it easier to access. Accepted answer!

Comment: Have you found a corresponding process that works for Docs? I've tried to do something similar and Chrome downloads a JSON document instead of loading the Google Doc in the viewport.

Comment: What does the change to `/revisions` and `sid=`, do?

Answer (score 8):

It depends.

For files that were **uploaded** to Google Drive: yes, this is directly supported (as explained in the official [help regarding file versions](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045)).  Select the "Manage revisions" menu-item for the uploaded file, available either by right-clicking on it, or by selecting it and then expanding the "More" dropdown menu.  A separate permalink will be available for each individual revision.

For files that were **created** in Google Drive (as a "Document", "Presentation", "Spreadsheet", ... etc.): this is not directly supported, because the individual items inside the "Revision history" do not have associated permalinks.  However, as was mentioned in a previous comment, for any of the previous snapshots, you can temporarily restore to that version and copy it to a new file (whose name can include a version number or timestamp), with its own URL.

Comment: I don't like it, but it's a solution. Hopefully Google will let us link to revisions someday.

Comment: I was looking for the same as @NobleUplift, I have an important document that I need to share links pointing to a given historical revision. Looks so basic and is not possible to do it.

Comment: [Google's official help document](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2409045) shows ways to **download** a specific revision, but I can't see how to obtain a **URL** to a specific revision of a file. I did see a way to get a ["revision id" from the source code](http://i.imgur.com/3dsik26.png), but not sure how to translate that to a URL for the file at that revision.

Comment: Very interesting point @MikeEng!