# How can I link to revision history overview of a (word) document on Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, links, bookmarks

Is it possible to link directly to the revision history of a document in google docs, in particular a word document? I need to link to the revision overview, not a specific revision.

I tried to adopt the answer in an older thread, which shows you how to link to a specific revision but I didn't succeed: [How can I link to revision history on Google Docs?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/47662/how-can-i-link-to-revision-history-on-google-docs)

Ideally it should be a direct link which I can use as a bookmark. But the link doesn't have to link directly to the document revision overview. I could also link to a a script or s.th. similar, which then opens the revision history of my document if that makes it possible to implement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!